# Properly storing values passed in URL in Django

Tags: django

I have the following URL:

`http://localhost:8000/store/add/?points=5`

I want to extract the number of points from my URL.

In my `views.py`, I have:

`points = request.GET.get('points',0)`

The problem is that it never finds points, so it uses the default of 0.

Any insight into what I'm doing wrong?

My `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from store.models import Part, Category, UniPart, LibraryRequest
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list
from voting.views import vote_on_object


urlpatterns=patterns('',
#/store/
url(r'^$','store.views.all_models',name="all_models"),
#/integer/view_part
url(r'^(\d+)/view_part/$','store.views.view_part',name="view_part"),
url(r'^your_models/$','store.views.your_models',name="your_models"),#/your_model
url(r'^user_models/(?P<username>\w+)/$','store.views.user_models',name="user_models"),
url(r'^add/(?P<points>\d+)/','store.views.add_model'),
```

Snipped from `views.py`:

```
def add_model(request, points=None):
    print points
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your `urls.py` says that you should use following url `/store/add/5`, and in your `views.py` you need to have view

```
def add_model(request, points=None):
    print points
```

If you want `points` as a `GET` parameter change your `urls.py` as following:

```
url(r'^add$','store.views.add_model', name='add_model'),
```

And then you can pass `points` as `/store/add?points=5` and extract it from the URL as

`points = request.GET.get('points')`

**UPDATE**
Also in a future to avoid such problems I suggest you to add `name` parameter to your routes in `urls.py` (see above) and use `reverse` in your views (ex. `reverse('add_model', kwargs={'points': 5}`) and `url` in your templates (ex. `{% url 'add_model' 5 %}`)

In that case all urls in your application will be generated automatically based on routes in your `urls.py` files.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
points = request.GET.get('points')
```

If you are passing more than one variable it can be done in two ways:

**METHOD 1:**

In your **urls.py**.

```
(r'^store/add1/?integer=(?P<category>\d+)/?string=(?P<keyword>\w+)$', 'view_function_name'),
```

You can get the above values in your views using the following:

```
def function_name(request):
    int_value = request.GET.get('integer')
    str_value = reuest.GET.get('string')
```

And you can also use the pattern given below:

**METHOD 2:**

In your **urls.py**.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('model_name.views', 
      (r'^store/add1/(?P<integer>\d+)/(?P<string>\w+)/', 'function_name')
      )
```

In your **views.py**:

```
def function_name(request, integer= None, string = None):
    print integer
    print string
    #Do whatever you wish with this value
```

The second method will be more easy for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually going to end up passing about 3. Is there a way to do that without modifying urls.py? Is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: If you don't want to modify your urls.py, you can use method1. But using method2 will be more easier for you.

Comment: The problem is that my modifications in my url.py are leading to a page not found 404 error. I have `url(r'^add/(?P<points>\d+)','store.views.add_model',name="add_model")` in `urls.py`. When I had just `add` then it was fine.

Comment: Use following in your urls. `(r'^add/(?P<points>\d+)/', 'store.views.add_model')` and in your views `def add_model(request, points=None):`. Then you can use `points` to use the variable passed in your url.

Comment: I changed it to that. Still not finding the URL

Comment: Post your **urls.py** (even if is more than one), how you pass variables in them and your views.

Comment: Ok I did. In terms of passing variables to it, I'm just doing it through the template ex: `<a href="/store/add/?points={{score.score|multiply:5}}>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16932/discussion-between-arulmr-and-user1328021)